# Ruby: Trying to sneak another --option into Cucumber by monkey patching, but doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby, cucumber, monkeypatching

I have written a small monkey patch for Cucumber which lets it print out file paths in a different way so I can Cmd-doubleclick on them in OSX Terminal to open the files directly in TextMate:

```
module Cucumber
  module Ast
    class Scenario
      alias_method :old_file_colon_line, :file_colon_line

      def file_colon_line(*arg)
        self.class.textmate_colon_line(old_file_colon_line)
      end

      def self.textmate_colon_line(file_colon_line)
        file, line = file_colon_line.split(':')
        'txmt://open?url=file://' + File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../') + '/' + file + '&line=' + line
      end
    end
  end
end

class Proc
  alias_method :old_file_colon_line, :file_colon_line

  def file_colon_line
    Cucumber::Ast::Scenario::textmate_colon_line(old_file_colon_line)
  end
end
```

Because not everybody in my team is working with TextMate, I'd like to activate this monkey patch with a custom --txmt argument when calling Cucumber:

```
cucumber features/create_task.feature --txmt
```

This results in:

```
invalid option: --txmt (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

So I'm trying to monkey patch Cucumber like this:

```
module Cucumber
  module Cli
    class Options
      def self.parse!(args)
        # Do some stuff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But sadly this doesn't work, it seems like the `Cucumber::Cli::Options.parse!` method isn't overwritten with this approach, while with `Cucumber::Ast::Scenario` the same approach seems to work.

Any idea why? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of monkey patching, I would suggest using a custom formatter, like https://github.com/raldred/cucumber_textmate/

Then you can launch cucumber with the option `--format TextmateFormatter`

Comment: This is a valid suggestion, but I'd like the paths to be printed out in "TextMate-way" regardless which formatter is chosen.

Comment: I think I'm confused about what you're asking then. You want the paths printed out in a textmate way regardless of which formatter is chosen, but only when a specific commandline option is used? What's the difference between that and using a commandline option to ensure that the correct formatter is used (since what you're doing is formatting)?

Comment: When I'm creating a special formatter, I would only have this single formatter, but sometimes I want to use formatter X and sometimes formatter Y, and I always want to let X and Y print out textmate paths, while my collegue does never want that. Isn't this obvious? Or am I missing a point here? :)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense -- you like running cucumber inside the terminal (with a different formatter depending on your mood), and want to be able to control click on the results to quickly open textmate. To me, that seems like overkill -- why not just use the textmate formatter and run the cukes in tm, or copy&paste the filenames, or use cmd+p to quickly open files in tm? It just doesn't seem worth the hassle or complexity added by monkey-patching. But if you really want to do it that way, why not just switch based on the machine's hostname instead of needing a commandline switch?

Comment: I'm having Guard run in the background which automatically runs my cukes when something has changed in them. The whole thing's more a challenge for me to see whether I manage to create "full fledged" monkey patch that I can release on my blog and share with others. It's not that important, though - the method with the machine's hostname is fine, too. Thanks!